# How do I return a value from another column by matching an input from a function?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zKEt.png)

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `GetGPA`(sName VARCHAR(45)) RETURNS float
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
DECLARE grade FLOAT;
DECLARE sName VARCHAR(45);

SELECT GPA INTO grade
FROM student
WHERE studentName = sName;

RETURN grade;
END
```

I did the function and it returned null:
[Stored Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKuW8.png)

I tried returning a student's GPA using a function inputting a student's name.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetGPA (sname varchar(45)) 
  RETURNS float DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
 DECLARE grade FLOAT;
   SELECT GPA INTO grade
   FROM student
   WHERE StudentName = sName;
  RETURN grade;
END
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/AF9iO_l8

[Reference](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mysql-creating-stored-function/#:%7E:text=The%20CREATE%20FUNCTION%20statement%20is,from%20within%20a%20Mysql%20statement.)

The only problem in your function is `DECLARE sName VARCHAR(45);` remove that part and your function is ok

Answer (score 0):

when you used `Into` key word,that means you create temp table.
so far you should be use a variable that its type equal with GPA column and `set` value on in,finally return it:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `GetGPA`(sName VARCHAR(45)) RETURNS float
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
DECLARE @grade FLOAT;
DECLARE sName VARCHAR(45);

SELECT @grade=GPA  
FROM student
WHERE studentName = sName;

RETURN @grade;
END
```